# Corresponding Receive Routine of MPI_Bcast

Tags: mpi, parallel-processing

What would be the corresponding MPI receive routine of the broadcast routine, MPI_Bcast.

Namely, one processor broadcasts a message to a group, let's say all world, how I can have the message in these processes?

Thank you.

Regards

SRec

Answer (score 41, accepted):

MPI_Bcast is both the sender and the receiver call.

Consider the prototype for it.

```
int MPI_Bcast ( void *buffer, int count, MPI_Datatype datatype, int root, MPI_Comm comm )
```

All machines except for the machine with id = root are receivers.  The machine that has the id = root is the sender.

Comment: According to OpenMPI docs: MPI_Bcast broadcasts a message from the process with rank root to all processes of the group, itself included.